# como obtener el id de un checkbox? en jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

hice esta función

```
function buscarcheckbox(){
    var check;
    check = $( "#tabla_checkboxes").find( "input" ).prop('checked');
    check = check.attr('id');
    console.log(check);
  }
```

me sale el error **Uncaught TypeError: check.attr is not a function**, quisiera obtener el id de ese input que es un checkbox, la función me dice cual es el checkbox marcado, pero falla cuando intento obtener el atributo de id.

Comment: Seria de bastante ayuda si nos muestras la estructura de la parte del html de la que pertenece #tabla_checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues básicamente sucede porque en esta linea:

```
check = $( "#tabla_checkboxes").find( "input" ).prop('checked');
```

Estas guardando en la variable `check` el valor obtenido del metodo `prop()` al pasarle el `checked`, el cual puede ser `true` o `false`, es lo mismo que hacer `check = true`, y por ser un valor que ya esta desligado del elemento `html` te dará error al pesarla `attr()`.

**Te propongo lo siguiente:** crear una variable que almacene el elemento input, luego una variable que guarde el valor si es verdadero que fue seleccionado o no(esta es opcional pues puedes pasarle ese valor directamente en el `if`, pero para demostración la dejare), y finalmente otra variable que al comprobarse lo anterior se guarda la id del elemento:

```
function buscarcheckbox(){
    let input = $( "#tabla_checkboxes").find( "input" ) //guarda el elemento
    let isChecked = input.prop('checked'); //comprueba si esta o no seleccionado
    let checkedId;
    if(isChecked){ //si lo esta guardar el id en checkedId
        checkedId = input.attr('id');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes considerar un ejemplo como este:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var ids;
    
    ids = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('id');
    }).get();
    
    alert('IDS: ' + ids.join(', '));
});
```